# ARRAYFORMULA sum with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Let's say you have a list of employees by start date and department. You want to create an `ARRAYFORMULA` to calculate the total salary cost by month for each department [like in this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q9HAA_aQ5ik4cOtJOQ9u8k9ye0hun1EYTkZRrF8DFNY/edit#gid=0). The months will go out for several years so want to use `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Looking for an ARRAYFORMULA for G2 that will handle the calculation for row 2 which is the Sales department for all months. That formula can then be replicated in G3 and G4 to handle the other departments.

You can't use `SUMIFS` or `QUERY` inside `ARRAYFORMULA`. Since you need to use less than with dates to calculate the total you can't use `SUMIF` with composite keys. I tried using a `FILTER` inside `SUMIF`'s inside `ARRAYFORMULA` but doesn't look like you can use `FILTER` inside a `SUMIF`.

Any suggesting for creating an `ARRAYFORMULA` function to handle this that's still condense enough to manage?

Comment: query can't be used in an ARRAYFORMULA. Pivot tabls wont' address the situation and "if" doesn't work over ranges unless you have a thought that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Actually I can see OP's point now, because they want a _cumulative_ total it's difficult to see how you could do it with an array formula.

Comment: I can see a long way of doing it by matrix multiplying the pivot query result by a diagonal matrix but it would be quite a faff.

Comment: Oh - well I like a challenge anyway.

Comment: @I'-'I Not sure what cell you're referring to since H9 isn't in the matrix. But I added what the matrix result should be as an example of the the final output. It's salary costs in each month so if the salary is 1 in June, and another hire starts in July with a salary of 1, July's total salary cost is going to be 2

Answer (score 0):

Well as I said it is a lot of faffing about but you can do it by generating a diagonal matrix

```
1   1   1   1
0   1   1   1
0   0   1   1
0   0   0   1
```

and multiplying the results of a normal pivot query by it so you get the first column, sum of first two columns, first 3 etc.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(query(A:D,"select B,sum(D) where B <> '' group by B pivot C",1)),
mmult(n(query(A:D,"select B,sum(D) where B <> '' group by B pivot C",1)),
if(column(indirect("A1:"&address(countunique(C:C),countunique(B:B))))>=row(indirect("A1:"&address(countunique(C:C),countunique(B:B)))),1,0)),
query(A:D,"select B,sum(D) where B <> '' group by B pivot C",1)
))
```

[image]

Whether this fulfills the 'condense enough to manage' criterion is another matter.

**Alternative**

If you can tolerate a separate formula in cols G, H, I etc., here's an alternative approach. I'm still going to use queries but the problem is if one of the departments isn't in range for a particular date there will be fewer categories in columns H, I etc. than the list in column G and they won't match up. The simple answer after much thought is to set out-of-range values to zero -before- entering the query so for G2 you have

```
=sort(unique(B2:B))
```

to get the department names into alphabetical order

then in H2

```
=ArrayFormula(query({$A:$C,$D:$D*($C:$C<=H1)},"select sum(Col4) where Col1 <>'' group by Col2 label sum(Col4) ''"))
```

and just pull it across into column I,J etc.

See if this works for you.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help. Yeah that's a tough one to manage. Still searching for something cleaner. It's fine if we need to put a formula in H2, H3, H4 as I'm really trying to solve for not having to copy the formula dozens of times for each month

Comment: OK if that's the case then I can suggest an alternative - will add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @tom. Such a common use case to be able to do multiple conditions. I wish Google would put in a function or two like SUMIFS that could be used in ARRAYFORMULA, it would make things so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try these formulas:

1. Enter this ArrayFormula in `F1`:
   `= ArrayFormula(IFERROR( INDEX( TRANSPOSE( $C$1:$C$14 ),
   MATCH( 1, 1 + COUNTIF( E1:$E1, TRANSPOSE( $C$1:$C$14 ) ) + ( TRANSPOSE( $C$1:$C$14 ) = "" ), 0 ) ), "|" ))`

   [image]
2. Then copy it to `G1:K1`

   [image]
3. Enter this ArrayFormula in `F2`:
   `= ArrayFormula(IFERROR( INDEX( $B$1:$B$14,
   MATCH( 1, 1 + COUNTIF( F$1:F1, $B$1:$B$14 ) + ( $B$1:$B$14 = "" ), 0 ) ), "_" ))`

   [image]
4. Then copy it to `F3:F7`:

   [image]
5. Enter this standard formula in `G3`:
   `=IF( OR( EXACT( G$1, "|" ), EXACT( $F3, "_" ) ), "",
   SUMIFS( $D$1:$D$14, $B$1:$B$14, $F3, $C$1:$C$14, "<=" & G$1 ) )`

   [image]
6. Then copy it to `H3:K3,G4:K7`

   [image]